# Adding a new line to a textarea

Tags: php, html

I have this string that i am displaying in a textarea from the database: $content = "Lamuvidine 89%(Rsd = 6% ; n = 9)"; I would like to "Lamuvidine 89%" to be on the first line and the remaining parts of the string on the second line. I have tried to store the string in the db as "Lamuvidine 89%\n(Rsd = 6% ; n = 9)" - without quotes, note the new line i have added but nothing.

NOTE:
$content = "Lamuvidine 89%(Rsd = 6% ; n = 9)"; //the whole string is in a single row of a db column called content

The results should be

```
Lamuvidine 89% //should be bold
(Rsd = 6% ; n = 9)
```

I did this and stored in the db

```
<strong>Lamuvidine 89%</strong>\n
(Rsd = 6% ; n = 9)
```

I still yield no results, suggestions!

Comment: textareas do not show effects. To show a new line you can try adding wrap=hard to the textarea

Comment: any formatted text in textarea will be rendered as `plain text` only by browser, however, you are allowed to add white space, and `\n`

Comment: wrap hard is already there in the properties

Comment: Why are you putting formatted text in a textarea? do you need it to be editable? In that case, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable. If it's static, just take it out of the textarea (maybe put it in a div which is styled how you want).

Comment: '\n' should be working over there. Hope you need to escape the '\n' before entering them to db.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `\n` with `<br />` if you are trying to do a line break

```
$content = "<b>Lamuvidine 89%<b><br />(Rsd = 6% ; n = 9)";
```

Answer (score 0):

insert into your database like this "`Lamuvidine 89%<br>(Rsd = 6% ; n = 9`)"

instead of `Lamuvidine 89%\n(Rsd = 6% ; n = 9)`

it will break the line

Comment: The whole of the string is stored in a single variable, meaning string substr() will have to be used first

Comment: use addslashes() while insert the data into db and use stripslashes() while get the data from db, should work

Answer (score 0):

As u know any formatted text in textarea will be rendered as plain text by browser, if u want to apply effects then u should use editable divs for that:

for a proper editable div that looks similar to textarea u just have to set

```
<div style="background-color:#fff;" contentEditable=true></div>
```

here is a working example which can help u [editable Div](http://jsbin.com/AGEtuRi/3/edit)